# Ubuntu 18.04 (ESXi 6.5) -- Live Server crashing -- Pasting 21 Lines

Tags: networking, 18.04, crash

Was wondering if anyone has experienced this with 18.04 where if you paste 20+ lines, where it hard locks the system. Looking in ESXi, Ubuntu usually uses about  29 MHz, but after pasting 20~21 lines, CPU spikes to 3.1 GHz and hard locks. Then I have to go to ESXi and reset it. I'm using this VM for a jumpbox for my lab network. Nothing is showing in the /var/log/kern.log as to point towards an issue. Below is what I was pasting:

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/27 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/28 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/29 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/30 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/31 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/32 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/33 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/34 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/35 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/36 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/37 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/38 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/39 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/40 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/41 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/42 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/43 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/44 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/45 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/46 disable
set interfaces ge-0/0/47 disable
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by VMXNET 3 some how. This issue also spread to all of my VMs running 18.04, including brand new installs with no patches.  I finally got an error message stating something about the driver. I migrated all of my vUbuntu 18.04 to e1000s and they've worked perfectly since.